# Laravel collection return value

Tags: php, laravel, collections

I've got this method in Laravel 5.4:

```
/**
     * Check if domain is valid
     *
     * @param string $emails
     * @param string $domain
     * @return bool
     */
    public function isValidDomain(string $emails, string $domain)
    {
        collect(explode(',', $emails))->each(function($email) use ($domain) {
            return $this->containsAtSymbol($email) && $this->getDomain($email) == $domain;
        });
    }
```

Here I check if the domain from an email adres is valid. So how could I say that when one of them is true, then return true:

```
return $this->containsAtSymbol($email) && $this->getDomain($email) == $domain;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use method [contains](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-contains) like this:

```
$result = collect(explode(',', $emails))->contains(function($email) use ($domain) {
   return $this->containsAtSymbol($email) && $this->getDomain($email) == $domain;
});
```

And the `$result` value will be `true` or `false`